# Filter array for every 3rd element

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble to create an array based on a dataset, I want to filter just some elements of it by choosing one element every 3. Could you help me with this?

This is what I did.

var example = dataset.map(function(d){return d.values
.filter(function(d,i){return (i+1)%3===0;})});

the dataset log: {name:"example1", values: Array(46)}

After applying the new array looks like this. And I'm looking for this [219, 2301, 239.....373]

[image]

Thanks

Comment: the value is in `d` variable

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you're trying to run your filter on every item in the array since you're doing it within an iteration of `Array.prototype.map`. You should filter the array for every third item first, and then run map on the resulting array to avoid mapping values that will end up being `null`.

```
const data = [...]

const dataSet = data
  .filter((_, i) => i % 3 === 0)
  .map(x => x.value)
```

You could also do it with a single use of `Array.prototype.reduce` and doing both filter and map in the same iteration like so:

```
const data = [...]

const dataSet = data.reduce((acc, curr, i) => {
  if (i % 3 === 0) acc.push(curr.value)
  return acc
}, [])
```